# Android: Set textcolor for programmatically created TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have created `TextView` programmatically, Now i want to set text color to the `TextView` below is my code

```
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.auditContent);
public TableRow row;
TextView txtNumber;

for (int i = 0; i < ItemCount; i++) {
row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    row.setWeightSum(1f);
      txtNumber = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
      txtNumber.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      txtNumber.setText("No." + count);
      txtNumber.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)); //setting text color

 row.addView(txtNumber);

ll.addView(row, i);
    }
```

The `textcolor` is not setting the color to `TextView` text, m doing anything wrong, And i debug the code there is no error. Please help thanks

In string.xml 
`<color name="blue">#33CCCC</color>`
m not using color.xml The above color will work fine for xml `TextView`

Comment: try this way `mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));`

Comment: the text color is not set to blue

Comment: Add Hex Value for Blue color

Comment: @Wizard Post your color.xml.

Comment: @Wizard Yes, I figured that much. Is it changed in any way? Does it just stay the same? Is the result the same as when you simply comment out the setTextcolor() Line?

Comment: Your code should work, are you sure the blue color in your resource is correct?

Comment: ya i used the same color for xml `TextView` it is working

Comment: @Thrakbad if i comment the same result no change

Comment: Show your color xml file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to your xml file you need to change

```
txtNumber.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

to

```
txtNumber.setTextColor(getResources().getString(R.color.blue));
```

Further more you can make `color.xml` file in your `values` folder and in that use

```
<color name="mycolor">#33CCCC</color>
```

now just use this way

```
txtNumber.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor));
```

Comment: M using for loop is there problem with that?

Comment: If you are using for loop then you can use TextView array

Comment: Ya i can that now i want to `setTextColor` to the `textview`

Comment: you can use textview[i].setTextColor();

Comment: `txtNumber[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));` not working

Answer (score 6):

**Starting from Android Support Library 23**

```
txtNumber.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color));
```

Answer (score 1):

tv_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));

Answer (score 0):

USe

```
text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
text.setTexColor(getResources().getColor()(R.color.colorname)
```

make sure your resources will be

#eaeaea

Comment: not a real solution when he needs the color from XML

Comment: @Thrakbad - can't you see the third option he has written that is fetching color from xml file, and setting it programmatically .

Answer (score 0):

//define global

```
int color;
```

// in on create

```
color = Integer.parseInt("YOUR COLOR CODE", 16)+0xFF000000;
{
 txtNumber = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
 txtNumber.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
 txtNumber.setTextColor(color); //setting text color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to set TextView color programmatically

```
private void setViewColor(TextView inputTextView, int colorId) {
    //From API 23, getResources().getColor() is deprecated
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        inputTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorId));
    } else {
        inputTextView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(colorId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this to change text color :

```
textview.setTextColor(new Color().parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: i m using this in every project . try this one time